# Bootstrap-vue dynamic toast isn't working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to use dynamic toast from bootstrap-vue. Here what I am trying to do:

```
<template>
 <b-button @click="handleClick(education)"></b-button>
</template>
```

```
<script>
import { notificationToast } from "@/components/NotificationToast";

export default{
 methods:{
  handleClick(){
   notificationToast(true);
 }
}
</script>
```

**NotificationToast.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { BVToastPlugin } from "bootstrap-vue";

Vue.use(BVToastPlugin);

let notificationToast = (append = false) => {
  this.$bvToast.toast(`This is toast`, {
    title: "BootstrapVue Toast",
    autoHideDelay: 5000,
    appendToast: append,
  });
};

export { notificationToast };
```

Whenever I click on the button it show the error :

*TypeError: Cannot read property '$bvToast' of undefined*

As it is mentioned in the [doc](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/toast#toasts-on-demand), I imported BVToastPlugin, still the problem is occurring. What to do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well. as shob answered, i found another solution useful, https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/6454

Comment: Issues I notice with the linked answer is you have an extra step inside every component where you want to use the toast.  You have to either:  1) Remember to add the imported function as a method, or 2) Remember to use `.bind`.  I think both options are less elegant than a single function whose arguments are clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the module, the `this` keyword does not refer to the Vue component.  The simplest workaround might be to make a second argument and pass in the context from the component:

```js
let notificationToast = (vm, append = false) => {
  vm.$bvToast.toast(`This is toast`, {
    title: "BootstrapVue Toast",
    autoHideDelay: 5000,
    appendToast: append,
  });
};
```

And call it like:

```js
notificationToast(this, true);
```